# Criar uma Imagem com texto dinâmico sobreposto e enviar por email

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins, plugin-wordpress

Necessitava criar um sistema que me permita ter 2 ou 3 imagens à escolha e nessas imagens seja possível inserir um texto escrito pelo utilizador e que por fim possa ser enviado por email com a imagem no corpo do email.

Algo do género disto: https://paginas.fe.up.pt/~natal/postais2015/postal1.html

Alguém sabe algum tutorial ou dar-me alguma luz de como o fazer?

Comment: Você quer enviar apenas uma imagem por e-mail ou você tem a opção de enviar um html montando imagem e texto?

Comment: Pode ser um html montando imagem e texto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça assim, coloquei ajustar à frente dos comandos que deve ajustar no seu caso:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if(isset($_POST['texto'], $_POST['imagem'], $_POST['email'])) {
        $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_POST['imagem']); // criar imagem
        $fontColor = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255); // cor do texto
        $font_path = './cour.ttf'; // Ajustar, tipo de fonte, neste caso está na mesma pasta deste script
        $text = $_POST['texto'];

        imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 0, 30, $fontColor, $font_path, $text); // posição/tamanho do texto
        $file = md5(time()). '.jpg'; // nome do ficheiro
        imagejpeg($jpg_image, 'imgsTests/' .$file); // Ajustar, pasta destino
        $imgSaved = 'http://migueldvl.com/heya/imgsTests/' .$file; // Ajustar path absoluto para imagem

        $message = '<html><body><img src="' .$imgSaved. '"></body></html>'; // Ajustar mensagem
        $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n"; // Ajustar
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n"; // Ajustar
        $headers .= "CC: susan@example.com\r\n"; // Ajustar
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
        mail($_POST['email'], 'My Subject', $message, $headers); // Ajustar, subject
        echo 'Imagem Enviada:<br><img src="' .$imgSaved. '">';
        imagedestroy($jpg_image);
    }
    else {
        echo 'Faltam dados';
    }
    die();
}
?>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email"><br>
    <input type="text" name="texto" placeholder="texto">
    <select name="imagem">
        <option value="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/Stonehenge.jpg">Image1</option>
        <option value="http://www.personal.psu.edu/jul229/mini.jpg">Image2</option>
        <option value="https://oss.adm.ntu.edu.sg/jays0001/wp-content/uploads/sites/38/2015/09/betterbusiness_jpg.jpg">Image3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: É isto que eu preciso, mas tem como definir oude o texto vai aparecer? pois em cada imagem vou necessitar ter o texto numa posição diferente na imagem. mas desde já agradeço pois já se fez alguma luz ;)

Comment: @LaranjaMecânica tem como definir o texto sim~na linha `imagettftext...`, coloquei em baixo um link para testar. preencha com o seu email e veja. Obgado

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer a inserção de texto você pode fazer facilmente com JS.
Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```js
            $(function(){
                $('#provider').keyup(function(){
                    $("#receiver").html($(this).val())
                });
            });
```

```css
            .block{position:relative;display: block;}
            .block img{position:absolute;top: 0px;left: 0px;width: 100%;max-width: 300px;z-index: 0;}
            .block span{
                position: relative;
                top: 20px;
                left: 50px;
                z-index: 1;
                color: #fff;
            }
            input{width: 500px;margin-top: 185px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
            <img src="http://shop.sharepoint.pt/WebRoot/ce_pt/Shops/260250/49BE/F9BB/1A81/F094/25FB/C0A8/8008/8E12/Cart_00E3_o_0020_Branco_0020_com_0020_Banda_0020_Magn_00E9_tica_0020_de_0020_Baixa_0020_Coercividade_0020__0096__0020_caixa_0020_de_0020_500_0020_Cart_00F5_es.jpg" alt="">
            <span id="receiver">[escreva aqui a sua mensagem]</span>
        </div>
        <br>
        <label for="">Escreva Aqui</label>
        <input type="text" value="[escreva aqui a sua mensagem]" id="provider">
```

Depois para enviar por email você pode enviar um HTML para a pessoa com as informações.

```
$to = 'exemple@example.com.br'; //Email que vai ser enviado
$from = 'meusite@exemple.com.br';//De quem
$subject = 'Website Cartão Personalizado'; //Assunto
$html = "SEU HTML AQUI"; //aqui você pode inserir o html gerado

//Config
$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

//função mail
mail($to, $subject, $html, $headers);
```

Espero ter ajudado.